# In logic puzzles, can I rely on "or" to mean "exclusive or"?

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

Is there a common rule for logic puzzles on whether the word "or" should be treated as inclusive or exclusive?  In computers, "or" is always inclusive.  In common speech, it seems most common for "or" to be exclusive.  (E.g. "you can have the fruit or the cake" means "one not both".)  Logic puzzles could belong in either camp.

For example, the puzzle I'm working on says (in effect), "Either X is true or Y is true".  I've proven that X is true.  Does this mean Y is guaranteed to be false?  As I usually do, I've deferred and not relied on the truth value of Y, but I've reached a point where I would need to exhaustively check many possibilities with lengthy implications just to avoid possibly mis-interpreting the meaning of the word "or" in a single clue.  Frustrating and not as fun.  I wish there was a common standard meaning for the word "or" in logic puzzles, as there is in computing.  (I found similar questions asked in math circles, but haven't yet found an answer that is both conclusive and unambiguous, which I expect in the realm of math.)

Comment: IMO if you go as far as to specify "**either** x or y", it's almost certainly an exclusive or.

Comment: (A) There can be no answer to this Question in general. (B) Can Puzzling Stack Exchange users Standardize to make a rule that "OR" is Inclusive & expect the whole world to follow it ? What about Existing Puzzles where "OR" is Exclusive ? (C) If you are asking only about Puzzles within Puzzling Stack Exchange , then the right place to ask is the Post which has the Puzzle you are attempting & the right Individual to answer is that Puzzle Maker. Everybody else is guessing. (D) If you are asking about a Puzzle you want to make , then you might easily include your "OR" rule in your Puzzle Post.

Answer (score 2):

When used with parallel constructions involving nouns or adjectives, the term "either" generally implies that the items being discussed are disjoint.  If all of the houses in a row are "either red or blue" that means that the row does not contain any objects which do not satisfy any of the following *inherently exclusive* constraints:

1. The object is not a house (and is thus not a red house and not a blue house)
2. The object is a red house and is not a blue house.
3. The object is a blue house and is not a red house.

When used with propositions, however, the usage is not as precise, especially in non-parallel constructs.  If one says "Everyone on this tour is either an adult or has a permission slip", the real meaning is likely that everyone on the tour satisfies one of the following inherently exclusive constraints:

1. The person is an adult [who wouldn't need a permission slip]
2. The person would need a permission slip, and has one

Note that the first category is *agnostic* with regard to the question of whether someone *has* a permission slip, and thus *does not exclude* adults who wouldn't need permission slips, but have them anyway.

Puzzle authors would be well advised to avoid such grammatical constructions, in favor of constructions such as "At least one of the following is true" or "Exactly one of the following is true".  Even if such wording comes across as a little bit stilted, it avoids any possible misinterpretation.